# Configure websocket always to be open

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I use this code to connect to NodeJS web socket:

```
useEffect(() => {      
        let futureResponseFeedAddress = "ws://localhost:/endpoint";
        const futureResponseClient = new W3CWebSocket(futureResponseFeedAddress);
        props.onUpdateOrderbookWebsocket(futureResponseClient);
        futureResponseClient.onopen = () => {
            console.log("WebSocket Client Connected on " + futureResponseFeedAddress);
        };
        futureResponseClient.onmessage = (message) => {
            ..............
        };
        futureResponseClient.onclose = closeEvent => {
            console.log("response messages websocket closed.");
        }

        return function cleanup() {
            futureResponseClient.close();
        };
    }, []);
```

But after around 1-2 minutes the messages are not received. Looks like I get timeout. Do you know how I can configure the web socket to be always open?

Comment: You can try use `require('websocket').client;` instead of `require('websocket').w3cwebsocket;`, maybe it help

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you should use socket.io for doing any real-time communication . It uses http long polling ,upgrades the connection to websocket if needed and it has also good browser support . It is much realiable too. But there are some drawbacks , your server need to use socket.io server api .

[Socket.io-client](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/)

[Socket.io-server](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/)

There is no need to re-invent the wheel .

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use it. How I can fix my code?

Comment: which language is your server using ? or is it a SPA ?

Comment: This is in react web app SPA based on React with JavaScript

Comment: The server is based on NodeJS.

Comment: If the server is based on nodejs . Then replacing "websocket" package with "socket.io" would not be that hard . If You don't have any other option . Then you should write a function have reconnects to the server , when the get lost . ` futureResponseClient.onclose = closeEvent => {
            console.log("response messages websocket closed.");// here put some code to reconnect to the server
        }`